# How to return a view as string value for an integer input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, string, model-view-controller, view

Example: The value store in database is 1 and the view for that must be like "Leave form"
how can I set this in asp.net MVC .

Comment: What are you trying to ask . have you tried anything?

Comment: Please add some code, so community will help you out.

Comment: i don't have any clues. And also i could not able to add code .while adding code they are showing some errors

Comment: public short? ActionTp { get
            {
                return ActionTp;
            } set
            {
                ActionTp = value;
            } }

Comment: can't u just use enum class and put it into the correct order.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i could not able to add codes .while adding code it is auto detecting errors